# Redis Protocol not accepting LPUS, HSET commands

Tags: redis

I am trying to do a mass insertion into redis using Redis Protocol format. But it is not accepting commands for LPUSH and HSET. Does Redis Protocol allow complex datatypes for Mass Insertion? `*3
$4
LPUSH
$5
Fruit
$5
Apple`

Comment: Redis Protocol supports all the usual Redis commands. Your example seems broken. LPUSH is 5 characters long, not 4. And is "Fruit" the name of your list, not a value?

Comment: Also, are you respecting the protocol's `\r` and `\n` rules?